# Checking if array contains two objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, foundation

I'm attempting to implement the containsObject but with two parameters, is this possible?

Currently I've got:

```
if ([ myArray containsObject:@"Object1", @"Object2"]){
    return result;
} else {
    return NO;
}
```

and apparently there's too many arguments. I've delved through Apple's docs but I'm yet to find anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: containsObject only takes one argument. Use the && operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
if ([ myArray containsObject:@"Object1" ] && [ myArray containsObject:@"Object 2" ] ){
    return result;
} else {
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There *is* too many arguments, containsObject is for a single object. (You can read its official documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject:)) To fix your problem, use the `&&` operator and call containsObject on each object individually.

```
if ([myArray containsObject:@"Object1"] && [myArray containsObject@"Object2"]){
    return result;
} else {
return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to evaluate them individually. Example:

```
bool MONNSArrayContainsAllObjectsIn(NSArray* const pArray, NSArray* const pSought) {
 assert(pArray);
 assert(pSought);
 assert(0 < pSought.count);

 for (id at in pSought) {
  if (false == [pArray containsObject:at]) {
   return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}
```

Then your code above becomes:

```
return MONNSArrayContainsAllObjectsIn(myArray, @[@"Object1", @"Object2"]);
```

If you are working with a known number of elements (2 in this case), then you can avoid creating the temporary array -- if you prefer to make that optimization and write out all variants you need, including parameters. Other answers detail this approach.

If you have large arrays and many comparisons to perform, `NSSet` may be better suited for your task.

Comment: At first this seemed unnecessarily complex, but it makes sense to craft a more abstract/flexible approach w/error-checking. Could you explain the purpose/benefit of `const`? If they're immutable NSArrays, why is `const` necessary?

Comment: Using varargs would also avoid creating a temporary `NSArray`.

Comment: @mc01 the const in this example applies to the pointer, rather than the object. const ObjC objects aren't very useful in practice. applying const to a pointer simply declares that the pointer's value may not change. this is independent of the presence/absence of const for the object. like many uses of const-introduction, it is not necessary, but an intention to aid developers (subjective). examples of operations forbidden by const pointers: `++pArray`, `--pArray`, `pArray = nil`, `pArray += 2`, `pArray = 0`, `pArray = pSought`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell absolutely +1. however, i would recommend the approach in my answer over variadics because it is safer.

Comment: Interesting - thanks! So intention is to prevent something like `pArray = someOtherObj` or `*pArray = *someOtherPointer`, ensuring that the parameter value is fixed for the life of the function (after which point it's `nil`?)? An Obj-C approach to address the sort of manipulation Swift only allows through variable & in-out parameters? (Or is that something entirely different?) Sorry - wrapping my head around things. Thanks

Comment: @mc01 you're welcome. `pArray = someOtherObj` is an example of the case the `const` prohibits. however, `*pArray = *someOtherPointer` is actually a value assignment to the referenced object. this assignment is forbidden by the compiler with ObjC types, but it is perfectly legal for C types (e.g. `int*`, `float*`, `struct*`). the `const` in this case is not information useful to the compiler -- it's useful for the programmer, where the compiler will emit an error if the pointer is reassigned (or otherwise mutated). chances are, the programmer did not intend to modify the parameter. (cont)

Comment: @mc01 it's a precaution which helps identify bugs at compilation, but it's not necessary.